# threejs v115 ,line20969:stencil Not working

Tags: three.js

///

```
var stencilWrite = material.stencilWrite;
            stencilBuffer.setTest( stencilWrite );
            if ( stencilWrite ) {

                stencilBuffer.setMask( material.stencilWriteMask );
                stencilBuffer.setFunc( material.stencilFunc, material.stencilRef, material.stencilFuncMask );
                stencilBuffer.setOp( material.stencilFail, material.stencilZFail, material.stencilZPass
```

);

```
        }
```

///
The above is the threejs code. After commenting, the following template function of my code can run normally. I do n’t know why? It seems that the value of material.stencilWrite and state.buffers.stencil.setTest (true) in maskPass are in conflict? When rrenderer.render (this.scene, this.camera); in the pass,  run stencilBuffer.setTest (stencilWrite); in the above code again?
///my code

```
var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(this.__scene, this.camera);
    renderPass.renderToScreen = true;
    renderPass.clearDepth = true;
    this.effectComposer.addPass(renderPass);

    var renderSelectPass = new THREE.RenderPass(this.selectScene, this.camera);
    renderSelectPass.clear = true;
    this.effectComposer.addPass(renderSelectPass);

    var maskPass = new THREE.MaskPass(this.selectFace, this.camera);
    maskPass.clear = true;
    maskPass.renderToScreen = true;
    this.effectComposer.addPass(maskPass);
```

///
It can run normally before the v106 version.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/hyok6tvj/? Or maybe by sharing a GitHub repository?

Comment: sorry,i can not.